# How to reduce pdf file size in Excel/VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In our company we use an Excel-file to register and generate purchase orders. One worksheet holds all data's. The other worksheet is only a template -which transform to a single standard A4 page, which looks roughly like in the [attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InyOM.jpg).
The problem is that the generated pdf-file is ~1MB, which is way more than I expect and wish.

What have I tried so far:

1. Standard Excel 'export as .pdf' - still >1MB
2. Export with VBA Sheets("template").ExportAsFixedFormat - still >1MB
3. Export with VBA as above with additional Quality:=xlQualityMinimum, still >1MB
4. Export with VBA as above with specified range - Sheets("template").Range(...), still >1MB
5. Reduce company logo size (to ~18KB), still >1MB
6. Hide unnecessary columns and rows, still >1MB
7. Change font from Calibri to Times New Roman - final file ~750KB
8. Standarize all font formating (bold, italic, font size) - final file ~500KB

Steps 7-8 are promising, but the company uses this template for years and don't want to change a font or formatting.

Is there any way I can reduce size of the final .pdf file?

Comment: My first thought, and strengthened by steps 7-8, is that Font Embedding is enabled. This adds significant overheard. I don't have Excel installed on this machine so I can't check right now, but check the font options in the Export dialog and turn off anything font related. Also, check if there are compression options, especially Image Compression as it's possible it is decompressing the company logo (i.e. it's 18KB when compressed but 1MB when a bitmap).

Comment: That's strange I have a PDF Export in Excel, 2 pages long including one image and differently formatted texts and I export with default parameters (nothing special) and it has about 160 kb. So either you have something really big image in there or something else is strange. • Try a new Excel file and check if a new file shows the same behaviour. That big files are unusual for what you show in the screenshot.